# OrientDB issue creating vertex in transaction

Tags: python, orientdb

I think there is a problem when creating records in a graph using transactions.
The vertices created during the transaction are always stored in the cluster #3, when I check on studio webapp the vertex created in the tx has class 'Unknown'

Here is the code:

```
client = pyorient.OrientDB("localhost", 2424)
client.connect("xxx", "xxx")
client.db_open("admin", "admin")

people_cluster = client.command("create class People extends V")
client.command("create vertex People content {'name': 'dummy', 'age': 21}")

attrs = {'@People': {'name': 'another_me', 'age': 31}}
res = client.record_create(people_cluster[0], attrs)

attrs2 = {'@People': {'name': 'me', 'age': 30}}
create_rec_cmd = ( client.get_message(pyorient.RECORD_CREATE) ).prepare((people_cluster[0], attrs2))

tx = tx.commit()
tx.begin()
tx.attach(create_rec_cmd)
tx.commit()

# This returns 'dummy' and 'another_me', but the people created in the tx is not present
res = client.command("select from People")

print(res[0]) => {'@People':{'age': 21, 'name': 'dummy', 'version':2,'rid':'#13:0'}
print(res[1]) => {'@People':{'age': 31, 'name': 'another_me'},'version':1,'rid':'#13:1'}

# The ones created in the transaction are found in the cluster #3, but with no class
print(client.command("select from #3:0")[0]) => {{'name': 'me', 'age': 30},'version':1,'rid':'#3:0'}
```

I have activated the debug option in the xml config, and the log doesn't give much information:

> 2015-08-16 17:59:46:992 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Read byte: 60 [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:46:994 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Reading int (4 bytes)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:46:995 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Read int: 6  [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:000 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Reading int (4
>    bytes)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:002 INFO {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Read int: 2113677732 [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:003 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Reading byte (1 byte)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:004 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Read byte: 1 [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:005 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Reading byte (1 byte)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:006 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Read byte: 1 [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:006 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Reading byte (1 byte)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:007 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Read byte: 3 [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:007 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Reading short (2 bytes)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:007 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Read short: -1
>   [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:008 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Reading long (8 bytes)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:008 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Read long: -2 [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:009 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Reading byte (1 byte)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:009 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Read byte: 100 [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:010 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Reading chunk of bytes. Reading chunk length as int (4 bytes)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:010 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Read chunk lenght: 18 [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:011 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Reading 18 bytes... [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:011 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Read 18 bytes: age:30,name:"me" [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:016 INFO {db=test}  /192.168.10.1:41317 - Reading byte (1 byte)... [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:017 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Read byte: 0 [OChannelBinaryServer]
>
> 2015-08-16 17:59:47:017 INFO  {db=test} /192.168.10.1:41317 - Reading chunk of bytes. Reading chunk length as int (4 bytes)... [OChannelBinaryServer]

Answer (score 0):

The [pyorient docs](https://github.com/mogui/pyorient) have the following example (with a few lines removed for clarity)...

```
tx = client.tx_commit()
tx.begin()

# create a new record
rec1 = { 'accommodation': 'home', 'work': 'some work', 'holiday': 'surf' }
rec_position1 = client.record_create( -1, rec1 )

tx.attach( rec_position1 )
```

The source code for [record_create](https://github.com/mogui/pyorient/blob/2440b1adddafbdaffdbd44d67219d86514ec7f86/pyorient/orient.py) is as follows...

```
def record_create(self, *args):
return self.get_message("RecordCreateMessage") \
    .prepare(args).send().fetch_response()
```

Your code is only running the `get_message` and the `prepare` functions, but not `send` and `fetch_response`. I suspect this is where your problem lies.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, but i dont have to tun send and fetch responde because that would send the msg to thr server immediately. The transaction handles that sending the commands attached when commited.  The records are been created, only that the ones in the transaction are stored in a different cluster with no class. In the test folder, the factory you can see they do it with msgs as i am doing it too. In the base message class theres an ungly "if" checking if in a transaction then dont send.